# Elasticsearch Integration test and spring-test doesn't work well together - AccessControlException

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, junit, spring-test

Looks like we can not have Junit test run with multiple runner. In my case, I need both RandomizedRunner (to be able to use/extend ESIntegTestCases) and SpringJUnit4ClassRunner to autowire classes under test.

As we can specify single @RunWith annotation. I kept @RunWith(RandomizedRunner.class). To activate spring junit test support added following to my test case.

```
@ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

@Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();
```

However, when I try to run the unit test with the above setup I am facing AccessControlException.

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:128)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:207)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:164)
    ... 17 more
```

Complete source of test case for reference:

```
import com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner;
import com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.annotations.ThreadLeakScope;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringMethodRule;


@RunWith(RandomizedRunner.class)
@ThreadLeakScope(ThreadLeakScope.Scope.NONE)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ProductSearchDemoApplication.class)
public class ProductSearchServiceTest extends ESIntegTestCase {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SubTestWithRunner test()");
    }
}
```

Would be great if someone can guide on how to ensure spring-test and ESIntegTestCase works together seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little bit late but we just faced many issues with `ESIntegTestCase` and wanted to share our solution. We end up using [Elasticsearch container](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/elasticsearch/) from [testcontainers.org](http://www.testcontainers.org) as an embedded Elasticsearch for our integration tests.

The advantage is that you could use any version of Elasticsearch and it's pretty easy to integrate into any project.